# How to make sure a specific decorator class isn't already decorating my object?

Tags: java, decorator

I have a decorator class that basically wraps around a class called Drink (Coffee Drink). You can decorate your beverage with a shot of espresso, chocolate, caramel. I know how to implement this and I did a very basic decorator implementation.

How could I alter my Whipped Cream class to make sure that it can only be added to the drink once?

```
public class WCream extends DrinkDecorator
{
   private final String TYPE = "Whipped Cream";
   private final double COST = 1.00;
   private Drink drink;


   public WCream(Drink d)
   {
      this.drink = d;  
   }

   public String getType()
   {
      return drink.getType() + ", " + TYPE;
   }

   public double cost()
   {
      return COST + drink.cost();
   }


}
```

This is the way I attempted to implement Singleton to make it work and this works to avoid duplicate whipped cream, but it skips over the next thing I add... so if I add chocolate after the whipped cream, it won't add the chocolate.

Then, in the tester class I used

```
myDrink = WCream.getUniqueInstance(myDrink); 
//instead of
myDrink = new WCream(myDrink);
```

which is the way I did it for the rest of the decorators.

```
public class WCream extends DrinkDecorator
{
   private final String TYPE = "Whipped Cream";
   private final double COST = 1.00;
   private Drink drink;

   private static Wcream uniqueInstance;


   public WCream(Drink d)
   {
      this.drink = d;  
   }

   public static WCream getUniqueInstance(Drink d)
   {
      if(uniqueInstance == null)
          uniqueInstance = new WCream(d)

      return uniqueInstance;
   }   

   public String getType()
   {
      return drink.getType() + ", " + TYPE;
   }

   public double cost()
   {
      return COST + drink.cost();
   }


}
```

Comment: 1. I bet DrinkDecorator implements or extends Drink, right?
2. I wouldn't call this "a singleton" but rather a condition on the decorator.

Comment: Use a `DrinkBuilder` that will handle these conditions for you.

Comment: Yes it does. It was suggested that I "modify singleton" to make it work but that works too. I don't want to fix it in the tester by asking if I've already added whipped cream. I want the drink to know if I have or not.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it's because it can be added dynamically. That's the purpose of [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Edited my original question to include much more info.

Comment: Even if using a singleton, you can do this: `WCream wcream = WCream.getUniqueInstance(WCream.getUniqueInstance(anotherDrink));`, which should not be supported.

Comment: The problem with `WCream.getUniqueInstance(myDrink)` is that, if I invoke it with `yoursDrink` it is going to return you mine, and we all going to share.

Comment: Maybe I could build this functionality into the constructor? I've tried a couple different ways but it doesn't seem to work. 

I can see why the singleton doesn't work though because only one whipped cream will ever be created.

Comment: In the constructor, you only know the current type of the Drink, not the type of their parents. Even if you could, it will be a bad design and defying the purpose of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Awful answer:

Validate it in your constructor using a String comparison

```
  public WCream(Drink d) {
    if (d.getType().containsAll("WHIPPED CREAM") { 
       KABOOOM
    }
    this.drink = d;
  }
```

Somewhat better:

Provide some method that returns the list of decorators or layers or something:

```
 public List<Components> getComponents() {
    List<Components> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(Component.WHIPPED_CREAM);
    list.addAll(this.drink.getComponents());
    return list;
 }
```

And then perform the same validation in your constructor, but now using just a regular collection contains

```
   public WCream(Drink d) {
    if (d.getComponents().contains(Component.WHIPPED CREAM)) { 
       KABOOOM
    }
    this.drink = d;
  }
```

Better answer, but it depends a lot on what you want to do:

Provide some kind of Builder which you can configure with what you want and at some point will assembly your Drink with all the needed Decorators, it will concetrate the somewhat difficult creation of your collaboration of objects and perform the needed validations

Comment: A set would be much better than a list for that purpose. Lookup is more efficient and uniqueness is guaranteed. Use a LinkedHashSet if you want to preserve order.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Yes if he ensures that only one of each component should be added. False if I can have my latte with double CINNAMON_SHOT.

Comment: True. Although I'd solve that by decorating the shot (decorating the decorator).

Comment: BTW, besides the lookup, creating the collection in that way is not efficient at all (more if we consider I am using ArrayList). I was looking if I can have something in java to build a collection like head :: tail (like I would do in a functional language) but I didnt found anything (nor look that much)

Comment: There is no functional list implementation in any of the libraries I know unfortunately. Perhaps functionaljava has one, I don't know. Actually there is one in the sources of the javac, but it feels weird to import a compiler just to get at a data structure it uses

Comment: just checked, there is one in functionaljava: http://www.functionaljava.org/javadoc/4.2/functionaljava/index.html?fj/data/hlist/HList.html

Comment: Cool `someHList.extend(head)` is what I was looking for. Too bad that for using that I would need to type the return type of my `getComponents` as `HList<Component>` instead of `List<Component>` but that's another issue